# Python: Searching a directory and subdirectories for a certain file type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search, directory

I have a folder that contains a few files of different types (`.cpp`, `.hpp`, `.ipp` ...) and in that folder are multiple sub-folders which also contain these different file types. My question is, is there a single loop that I can make that will search the first main folder and return a list full of all the `.cpp` files from either folder? So far, I know that:

`folder_list = [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if os.path.isdir(f)]`

will return a list of the sub-folders, and then I can change the working directory and get the files list to append.

I also know that:

```
file_list = [f for f in listdir(os.getcwd()) if isfile(join(os.getcwd(), f))]
```

will return a list of the files.

However, I won't know the names of these sub-folders (and therefore the directory) beforehand. Thank you for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `listdir` and `endswith` to identify characters at the end of a string:

```
filetypes = ['cpp', 'hpp', 'ipp']
dir = "target directory"

files = [[f for f in os.listdir(dir) if f.endswith(type_)] for type_ in filetypes]
```

This will result in list of lists where each list will hold files of specific type.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `pathlib.Path.rglob function`

```
from pathlib import Path
list(Path(".").rglob("*.cpp" ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `os.walk()`:

```
filetypes = ['.cpp', '.hpp', '.ipp']

for current_folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(dir):
    files = [f for f in files if f.endswith(filetype) for filetype in filetypes]
```

More info on `os.walk()` here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm